# Is there a way to show some "weighted" residuals after LinearModelFit?

Tags: fitting

I am fitting some functions to some data and then I want to analyze the residuals of that fit. I'd like to see how those residuals compare to the values of the original data, hence my "weighted" in the title. This because, if I get a minimum residual of -0.5 and maximum of 0.5, these are very low if the data's coordinates is around 50, but is very high if the data goes around 0.5.

Taking the examples in the Wolfram KB:

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0.05}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}};
lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x];
lm["FitResiduals"]
(* {0.791525, -0.849153, -0.280508, 0.338136} *)

data2 = {{0, 0.01}, {1, 0.0005}, {3, 0.02}, {5, 0.04}};
lm2 = LinearModelFit[data2, x, x];
lm2["FitResiduals"]
(* {0.00791525, -0.00849153, -0.00280508, 0.00338136} *)
```

I could do what I wanted in this way:

```
totransform = 
 Flatten[#] & /@ Map[{data[[#]], lm["FitResiduals"][[#]]} &, Range[1, Length@data]];
totransform /. {a_, b_, c_} -> {a, c/b}
(* {{0, 0.791525}, {1, -16.9831}, {3, -0.140254}, {5, 0.0845339}} *)
(*this is what I want*)
```

However, this is not very elegant... Do you see any easier way to accomplish this? Is there some function already built to take out these "weighted" residuals?

Thank you for all your help

Comment: you may try `Rescale`. something like: `data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0.05}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}};
dat=Rescale[data, {-0.5, 0.5}]
lm = LinearModelFit[dat, x, x];
lm["FitResiduals"]`

Comment: Wait ... if you want smaller residuals for smaller values, why don't you just weight your points accordingly when using `LinearModelFit[]`?

Comment: eh @belisarius, hand't thought about that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0.05}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}};
lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x];
```

You can also use

```
Transpose[{data[[All, 1]], lm["FitResiduals"]/data[[All, 2]]}]
(* {{0, 0.791525}, {1, -16.9831}, {3, -0.140254}, {5, 0.0845339}} *)
```

or

```
Transpose[{First@#, lm["FitResiduals"]/Last@#} &@Transpose[data]]
(* {{0, 0.791525}, {1, -16.9831}, {3, -0.140254}, {5, 0.0845339}} *)
```

Alternatively, define a function that takes as input a data set and a model an returns weighted residuals:

```
ClearAll[trnsfrmF];
trnsfrmF = Transpose[{#[[All, 1]], #2["FitResiduals"]/#[[All, 2]]}] &;

trnsfrmF[data, lm]
(* {{0, 0.791525}, {1, -16.9831}, {3, -0.140254}, {5, 0.0845339}} *)
```